# Calculating Column space, row space and solution space of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&-4&0&3&1 \\ -3&12&9&27&15 \\-3&12&-3&-21&-9 \end{bmatrix}$$

(a) Find a basis for the column space of A.

Solution: ${(1,-3,-3),\ (0,9,-3)}$

(b) What is the dimension of the solution space of A?

Solution: 3

Solution space: $$\{ \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -3\\ 0\\-4\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}  -1\\ 0\\-2\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} 
 \}$$

(C) Let v= $\begin{bmatrix} -6\\-3\\a\\-1\\-3 \end{bmatrix}$ where a $ \epsilon \ \mathbb {R}$.  Find the value of a such that v is in the solution space of A.

can someone please help me with c?

Comment: Do you have any idea When can $v$ be in solution space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Av=\begin{pmatrix}                                          
0 \\                                                  
9a-90\\
30-3a\\
\end{pmatrix}$
So you require $a=10$.